# How to loop through list and when contains word change color

Tags: jquery

So I need to make a search field with a button and when you put in a word in the search field and then press that button it needs to loop through a list. And when the list contains the word you've put in, the background color of the item (word) needs to change.

I made a search field with a button and list in HTML. I wrote something in JQuery, but I really need help. This is hard.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("li").each(function(i, element){
            if($(this).css {
                return = '#304878';
            }
        });
    })

});
```

Comment: Hint: You'll make use of `$(this).text()`, `$(this).css('color', '#304878')` and `$('input').val()` (or similar - depending on how many input's are on the page, you may need a selector specific to your search field). There's really not a full question here, but that's what I've got.

Comment: `{
                return = '#304878';
            }` is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Highlighted the search text with color in the string when click on the search button.
[image]
Try the below code.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
 $("button").click(function(){
  
  //Remove the span tag from the text which have class 'highlight'
  $('.add_content').find("span").each(function(index) {
   if($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith(text);
   }
  });
  
  //On click get the search text and highlight. 
  var string_search =  $('#search_box').val();
  $('li').each(function(){
  
   //Enable the case insensitive
   reg = new RegExp(string_search, 'gi');
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(reg, function(str) {
    return '<span class="highlight">'+str+'</span>'
   }));
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.highlight{
 color:#304878;
}
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="search_box" name = "search_box">
    <button name="search_buttoon">Search Button</button>
   <ul class="add_content">
 <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</li>
 <li>ndustry. Lorem Ipsum has been</li>
 <li>It is a long established fact that a reader</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please remove the horizontal scollbars. It improves the readability.

Comment: @reporter I removed the scollbars.